# Proxychains does not work correctly in Kali linux (Virtual Machine)

Tags: linux, firefox, tor

I cannot open duckduckgo or any site with proxychains as shown, And there is a number 4 at the end of it for some reason. [Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIFS7.png)

`/etc/proxychains4.conf`

```
# proxychains.conf  VER 4.x
#
#        HTTP, SOCKS4a, SOCKS5 tunneling proxifier with DNS.


# The option below identifies how the ProxyList is treated.
# only one option should be uncommented at time,
# otherwise the last appearing option will be accepted
#
dynamic_chain
#
# Dynamic - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# at least one proxy must be online to play in chain
# (dead proxies are skipped)
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#strict_chain
#
# Strict - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# all proxies must be online to play in chain
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#round_robin_chain
#
# Round Robin - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# of chain_len length
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# at least one proxy must be online to play in chain
# (dead proxies are skipped).
# the start of the current proxy chain is the proxy after the last
# proxy in the previously invoked proxy chain.
# if the end of the proxy chain is reached while looking for proxies
# start at the beginning again.
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
# These semantics are not guaranteed in a multithreaded environment.
#
#random_chain
#
# Random - Each connection will be done via random proxy
# (or proxy chain, see  chain_len) from the list.
# this option is good to test your IDS :)

# Make sense only if random_chain or round_robin_chain
#chain_len = 2

# Quiet mode (no output from library)
#quiet_mode

#Proxy DNS requests - no leak for DNS data
proxy_dns

# set the class A subnet number to use for the internal remote DNS mapping
# we use the reserved 224.x.x.x range by default,
# if the proxified app does a DNS request, we will return an IP from that range.
# on further accesses to this ip we will send the saved DNS name to the proxy.
# in case some control-freak app checks the returned ip, and denies to 
# connect, you can use another subnet, e.g. 10.x.x.x or 127.x.x.x.
# of course you should make sure that the proxified app does not need
# *real* access to this subnet. 
# i.e. dont use the same subnet then in the localnet section
#remote_dns_subnet 127 
#remote_dns_subnet 10
remote_dns_subnet 224

# Some timeouts in milliseconds
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000
### Examples for localnet exclusion
## localnet ranges will *not* use a proxy to connect.
## Exclude connections to 192.168.1.0/24 with port 80
# localnet 192.168.1.0:80/255.255.255.0

## Exclude connections to 192.168.100.0/24
# localnet 192.168.100.0/255.255.255.0

## Exclude connections to ANYwhere with port 80
# localnet 0.0.0.0:80/0.0.0.0

## RFC5735 Loopback address range
## if you enable this, you have to make sure remote_dns_subnet is not 127
## you'll need to enable it if you want to use an application that 
## connects to localhost.
# localnet 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0

## RFC1918 Private Address Ranges
# localnet 10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0
# localnet 172.16.0.0/255.240.0.0
# localnet 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0

# ProxyList format
#       type  ip  port [user pass]
#       (values separated by 'tab' or 'blank')
#
#       only numeric ipv4 addresses are valid
#
#
#        Examples:
#
#               socks5  192.168.67.78   1080    lamer   secret
#               http    192.168.89.3    8080    justu   hidden
#               socks4  192.168.1.49    1080
#               http    192.168.39.93   8080    
#               
#
#       proxy types: http, socks4, socks5
#        ( auth types supported: "basic"-http  "user/pass"-socks )
#
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
socks4 127.0.0.1 9050
socks5 127.0.0.1 9050
```

UPDATE: I uninstalled it then reinstall it again and it still doesn't work [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqxzg.png)

UPDATE 2: I tried it without going into root and it worked. But does it make a difference?

Comment: `no DISPLAY environment variable specified` is the key. Investigate this. I think the issue has nothing to do with `proxychains`.

Comment: Use curl or socat to do tests, not a complex browser run as root. Once it works with basic tools, try more complex tools.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue (12/27/2021) on kali linux. By guessing I needed to give it directions on how to display I modified the command to:
proxychains firefox open [www.duckduckgo.com](http://www.duckduckgo.com)

and it worked by simply adding "open"
It did open a second tab, so I'm not sure if that's the default or needs more tweaking, but it opened the page and proxychain worked.